# Creating a system image that has no persistant storage?

Tags: filesystems, system-installation, disk-image

So I would like to create a system image, that I can tell grub to boot to every time, but with only temporary memory. I would like to create a system image that is fully installed and set up and then utilize that in this sort of volatile box. Basically meaning any changes made stay while it is booted, but after a restart it starts from the same place.

I know it is possible by making something like a squashfs image then telling grub to boot the image every time using a temporary storage partition; however, I'm not sure how to do it. How would you go about not only creating, but using say a bare bones debian image in this manner?

Comment: What you describe looks like [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) right ? If you really want to build your own amnesic distribution, I would look at the technical documentation to figure out the steps involved.

Comment: Well yes but no, I would like to use a base debain image that I can modify and mess around wih whenever booted, for testing purposes, and when I am done I would like to just reboot and start again from scratch. This would be probably be done without virtualization. I might turn to docker however.

Comment: Then use a Debian Live CD/USB: it fits your description, including of course being based on Debian. There are tools to build a custom version, and again there's documentation to read. https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-live/ , https://live-team.pages.debian.net/live-manual/

Comment: Welcome! You want a *custom* image, or a regular live OS will do?

Comment: Something of a live USB but not on USB, on a single file(preferably), and able to be booted to by perhaps using grub or something of the sort. I think that a custom image fits the description better.

Answer (score 0):

Booting a live iso image: example with Debian. In this example my configuration is as follow:

- My installed OS (Debian) is in (EFI) partition `hd0,gpt5`
- I use the iso image `debian-live-10.3.0-amd64-gnome+nonfree.iso`.
- I placed the iso under `/home/user/Live`

> You have to change the `40_custom` file (see below) depending on your setup.

1. Get the [iso image](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/).
2. Open with sudo `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and add:

   ```
   set root=(hd0,gpt5) # here the partition where you placed your iso
   set iso_path=/home/user/Live/debian-live-10.3.0-amd64-gnome+nonfree.iso
   loopback loop $iso_path
   ```
3. Open the iso with the file manager and open `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.
4. Copy this part, paste below the previous code:

   ```
   menuentry "Debian GNU/Linux Live (kernel 4.19.0-8-amd64)" {
     linux  /live/vmlinuz-4.19.0-8-amd64 boot=live components splash quiet "${loopback}"
     initrd /live/initrd.img-4.19.0-8-amd64
   }
   ```
5. Change to:

   ```
   menuentry "Debian GNU/Linux Live (kernel 4.19.0-8-amd64)" {
     linux  (loop)/live/vmlinuz-4.19.0-8-amd64 boot=live components splash quiet findiso=$iso_path
     initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img-4.19.0-8-amd64
   }
   ```

The file `40_custom` in full:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.


set root=(hd0,gpt5) # here the partition where you placed your iso
set iso_path=/home/user/Live/debian-live-10.3.0-amd64-gnome+nonfree.iso
loopback loop $iso_path

menuentry "Debian GNU/Linux Live (kernel 4.19.0-8-amd64)" {
  linux  (loop)/live/vmlinuz-4.19.0-8-amd64 boot=live components splash quiet findiso=$iso_path
  initrd (loop)/live/initrd.img-4.19.0-8-amd64
}
```

6. Run `update-grub`.

> Next time you reboot, you will have a new entry in GRUB that runs a live OS.